# Java Applet java.awt.Choice Add Item not working for second time

Tags: java, applet

I am writing an applet which contains a panel (PanelCondition) with a java.awt.choice dropdown.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html

```
public class PanelCondition extends Panel
{
  Choice choiceCond = new Choice();
  public PanelCondition(bool isGood)
  {
      setCond(isGood);
  }

  private void setCond(boolean isGood) 
  {
    condCode = getCondItems(isGood);
    this.choiceCond.removeAll();

    for (int i=0; i < condCode.length; i++) 
    {
      this.choiceCond.addItem(condCode[i]);
    }

    this.choiceCond.repaint();
  }
...
}
```

The PanelCondition is included in a java.awt.Frame

```
public class FrameExample extends Frame
{
    PanelCondition cond;
    private void setCond(bool isGood)   
    {
       cond = new PanelCondition(isGood)
       this.add(orderCond,...)
       ...
    }
}
```

When the FrameExample.setCond() is called first time (isGood=true), the correct items are added to the dropdownlist. However if I call the setCond() the second time (isGood=false), the dropdownlist items don't have any changes.

I have tried to call this.choiceCond.validate() or this.choiceCond.repaint, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using AWT or could we tempt into the 21st century with Swing? Oh, and don't see any applets in your code ;)

Comment: I have to admit it is an old program. Anyway, I have tried to use javax.swing.JComboBox, but the result is just the same.

Comment: Well, `cond = new PanelCondition(isGood)` looks wrong to me, but I'm only guessing. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer, I have tried not to create a new PanelCondition each time, and call the PanelCondition.setCond() for second time and it works. But I still don't understand why creating a new Panel the second time causes the problem.

Comment: Well, it's a little hard to 100% sure, but basically, you could be adding the new `PanelCondition` which is probably been painted underneath the other or not laid out or some other such, which is leaving the original one on the screen

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. Can you answer the question properly? Let me mark you down as an accepted answer.

Comment: To test whether the new PanelCondition is painted underneath the other, I call the this.remove(this.cond) before new PanelCondition the second time and it's okay.

Comment: Due to runtime expense of creating a new object and adding it to the screen, which could cause multiple updates, it's generally preferred to update what's already there if possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further evidence,

```
cond = new PanelCondition(isGood)
this.add(orderCond,...)
```

Looks suspicious.  This is likely just adding another `PanelCondition` to the UI, but it may be covered by the pre-existing instance.

Generally, it's easy just to update the pre-existing instance...

```
//cond = new PanelCondition(isGood)
//this.add(orderCond,...)
cond.setCond(isGood);
```